# Mouse over event of jquery too fast

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseover

I have to show something on the navigation bar(with 8 items).

I have used `mouseover` on the navigation bar to display a certain set of items. The problem is the `mouseover` is too fast. Is there any way to delay this event?  I just want to show some div(with data) on mouse over.

Please note i want to show my div on mouse hover and hide my div when mouse leave.Please suggest how can I use this with some mouse event?

My sample code:
    $(document).on('mouseover', '.menu', function(argument) {
        $(this).find('.drop-down').css('display', 'block');
    });
    $(document).on('mouseout', '.menu', function(argument) {
        $(this).find('.drop-down').css('display', 'none');
    })

Comment: Please post some code showing what you've tried.

Comment: Can i use some other function instead of mouse over and mouseout

Comment: My Code :  $(document).on('mouseover', '.menu', function(argument) {
        $(this).find('.drop-down').css('display', 'block');
    });
    $(document).on('mouseout', '.menu', function(argument) {
        $(this).find('.drop-down').css('display', 'none');
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can use the delay() funtion, it would help you to get the desired result,
Here's the syntax,

```
                    $(selector).delay(speed,queueName)
```

The delay() method sets a timer to delay the execution of the next item in the queue.

There's a very nice example of delay function here - [jQuery delay() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_delay)

Comment: @user2814546, Please Accept the answer if it helps you !

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` for delay (not only for jquery, it is better than `delay` due to possibility to cancel execution). Here is the example for a menu:

```
timer = setTimeout(function(){
    $this.find('.drop-down').show();
    timer = null;
    }, 400);
```

```js
var timer;
var timerOut;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menu').on('mouseover', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // clear existing timer to prevent showing another dropdown
    if(timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      $this.find('.drop-down').show();
      timer = null;
    }, 400);
  });
  $('.menu').on('mouseout', function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    timerOut = setTimeout(function(){
      $this.find('.drop-down').hide();
      timer = null;
    }, 400);
  });
});
```

```css
.menu{
  font-size:14px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.drop-down{
  display:none;
  font-size:12px;
  padding-left:10px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <a>Menu1</a>
  <div class="drop-down">drop1.1</div>
  <div class="drop-down">drop2.1</div>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <a>Menu2</a>
  <div class="drop-down">drop1.2</div>
  <div class="drop-down">drop2.2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have use the function like this : $(document).on('mouseover', '.menu', function(argument) {
        $(this).find('.drop-down').css('display', 'block');
    });
    $(document).on('mouseout', '.menu', function(argument) {
        $(this).find('.drop-down').css('display', 'none');
    })

Comment: You probably need that it doesn't hide in case mouse returns back in delay time, don't you?